# Are these Firebase deeplink warnings harmful in a deployed app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

My Android app is still in development. I have integrated the Firebase deep linking feature in my app. When I share the link and user clicks on it, it goes to app or app store accordingly.

But when I got to the browser and try to debug the link by adding **?d=1**, it shows the below warnnings...

1. Param 'link' must not be on FDL domain.
2. Android app 'com.log.yari' lacks SHA256. AppLinks is not enabled for the app.

I tried to find out on these issues but couldn't found much.

My question is, will there be any issue if I deploy my app on google play with these warnings?

Thanks in advance

Comment: all warnings are harmful. Just the severity differs

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Harmful in the sense? I am not getting much help on SHA256 and FDL domain..

Comment: Murphy's Law: `If it can go wrong, it will go wrong`. Sure, the warnings may not impact a major portion of your code base, but it will impact some.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug

Comment: When I got to Firebase in my app it shows SHA1 certificate is already present. Is this different from SHA256?

Comment: Yes, those 2 are seperate encryption mechanisms. To be precise, SHA256 is SHA2

Comment: Do you know any step by step tutorial for getting SHA256? I can/should not go live with SHA1 and without SHA256?

Comment: Get SHA256 from keytool just like with SHA1, and paste it into the Firebase console exactly the same way as you did with SHA1 (Settings screen, add fingerprint)

Comment: The link one indicates your link might be not well formed - try making one in the console to test.

Comment: For SHA1 I did nothing.. I think the Android studio did everything for me. I can see the SHA1 in Firebase settings page. I will try to generate SHA256 but not fining any good example to do so..

Answer (score 2):

> Param 'link' should not be on FDL domain. [Learn more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually?authuser=1#general-params).

This warning happens when you include the short url link prefix i.e `https://yourdomain.page.link/a1b2` inside the Deep link url i.e `https://google.com/path?someParameter=1`.

So wrong way:

Deep link url = `https://yourdomain.page.link/?link=https://google.com/path?someParameter=1`

What you need to do:

Deep link url = `https://google.com/path?someParameter=1`

Because Firebase will auto-generate the long dynamic link that looks like the *wrong way deep link url* at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem if your Dynamic Links conflict with your web URLs. It's a warning because it's not entirely wrong, you just have to be very careful.

Here's the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains#using_your_web_domain_for) and some ideas how to avoid this situation.